# arraylist vs linked list .why linked list is slower when we add in the end?

Tags: java, microbenchmark

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class CompareList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> ArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> LinkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    doCalculations("ArrayList",ArrayList);
    doCalculations("LinkedList",LinkedList);    
}
private static void doCalculations(String type,List<Integer> List){
    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++){
        List.add(i);    
    }
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    /*
     To add elements in the end 
    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++){
        List.add(i);    
    }
    */
    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++){
        List.add(0,i);
    }
    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time taken" +" "+ (end-start) + "ms for" +" "+ type);
}
}
```

time taken 13ms for ArrayList
time taken 64ms for LinkedList

i know this is duplicate question ,but please don't remove this ,whatever answers they gave to this question i was unable understand ,Can anyone explain this in simple words why this linked list is slower when we add element in the end?

Comment: Because benchmarking is hard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Sorry but your test is completely broken. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Try reversing the call of `doCalculations` in your `main` method and you will get completely different results ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what do you mean by reversing?

Comment: Call `doCalculations("LinkedList",LinkedList)` first, then `doCalculations("ArrayList",ArrayList);` and you'll see.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why is timings different now? these kind of things makes me sometimes hate programming :(

Comment: @saurabhkumar Read the links ZouZou and I provided, and you might understand. Long story short, benchmarks are hard.

Comment: @user3580294 they are hard if you try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Even with a proper benchmark, List.add(0,i) should be *significantly* slower on an ArrayList because it has to move all the existing elements to the right each time, whereas the LinkedList just appends a node to the front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're currently doing here is a micro benchmark. This is not an easy task, because you have to take into account all these tips: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197).

Still, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. There are frameworks that ease this work like [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) and [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) that help you to perform real benchmarks for your pieces of code/algorithms by using JUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

linked list is slower  cuz  it is  like a train.......it  have to check each element  and check it is value ..until   it find  the  matched element..so think of it like chained train and you want to go from the first  of the train to the end

Comment: but then why its faster ?